# Can a license purchased in one country be used in another country?

Tags: license

My company has branches in France and India. The France office has bought sharepoint licenses for the development center in India.

My IT support team says that they cannot use the licenses here in India. Are there any issues in using those licenses in India? France center will not be using those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all down to the way the world is divided into licensing areas. Much like DVD movies have regions (North America Region 1, Europe Region 2, etc, etc). So do license from most coporations like e.g. Microsoft, Adobe and Symantec.

France is covered under the EMEA license group (Europe, Middle East and Africa) and as such, the France office could (EULA permitting) transfer license for any of those areas. Sadly India does not share a license terriory ([Microsoft's License Regions](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/open-regional.aspx)) with France so they could not be transferred.

The crux of the issue for you, is whether France bought EMEA licenses for themselves or Indian licenses for India? Or do you have an global enterprise agreement in place with Microsoft which would smooth everything out nicely?

Comment: Thanks Szetek. Does this apply to development licenses too?

Comment: Yes, after all a development license is another type of license (as opposed to intranet/ extranet/ internet MOSS licenses) and still needs to be purchased for the correct area the development will be undertaken in.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have a big and serious company. Seek professional advice from your legal division. There are many ways to license software from Microsoft. We do not know enough details about your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in Microsofts license agreement about which country you can use the license in. There might be local laws/issues preventing the use of software bought outside the country. If your local team knows about the issue they should be able to direct you to the correct resources.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware license belong to the company, and are not linked to the country of purchase. However there could be local laws that require software to be purchased within the region.

I will look for the official documentation on this.