# Is a Windows 7 license key country specific?

Tags: windows-7, license, windows-activation

I am specifically interested in Retail versions of the OS. I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/24125/can-a-license-purchased-in-one-country-be-used-in-another-country) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/197330/is-a-license-key-for-windows-7-professional-valid-for-different-languages) on the site, but they are both quite old, so I was wondering if anything had changed in the meantime.

Basically, if I buy a retail copy of Windows 7 from Amazon UK, can I then use it and activate it in another European country?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit): "In some specific cases, license keys may be *geographically restricted*. For example, Windows 7 Home Basic is only available in certain countries like China. For more information, read [Geographically Restricted Microsoft Software](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/geoinfo.aspx)."

Comment: @and31415 thanks for the links :) I suppose then that "standard" versions of Windows (Home Premium, Professional etc) can be bought and used anywhere?